# Which method is better to store data in database and make one-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, sqlite, database-design

I've a problem i'm looking at different methods of storing data in database.. and cant decided which one is better then other.. for example we are making multi user blogging website and want to store data of post and relate it with authors(user) as one to many relationship.

1. the first way is to make two tables

   - post:

     - post_id
     - post_title
     - post_body
     - user_id
     - post_timestamp
   - user:

     - user_id
     - user_name
     - user_email
     - user_password
     - user_timestamp
2. The sec way is to make 3 table

   - post:

     - post_id
     - post_title
     - post_body
     - post_timestamp
   - user:

     - user_id
     - user_name
     - user_email
     - user_password
     - user_timestamp
   - post_user:

     - post_user_id
     - user_id
     - post_id
     - user_timestamp

so which method is more efficient and professional?

Comment: Typically, a post only has one sender, and multiple recipients. This fact often informs the structure of the database.

Comment: thanks for reply yup you are right but i'm more concern about how to store should i store user_id with post table or i should store user_id and post_id in separate table and link both column with foreign key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One:many -- The `id` of the "one" is in the "many" table, and indexed.  In your example, `user_id` would be in the table `Posts`.

Many:many -- This is an extra table with pairs of ids.  (Example:  Many students taking many classes.)  More discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table